# Having hierarchical groups in ini file for QSettings

Tags: qt, ini

I am using QSettings to make changes in my GUI.
Currently I have understood how to use QSetting for basic key=value pairs.

```
[button]
  enable = 1
```

But I want to have hierarchical groups. Something like below

```
[user1]
  [button1]
     enable = 1
  [button2]
    enable = 0
[user2]
  [button1]
    enable = 1
  [button2]
    enable = 0
```

Is there any way to do this?

Thank You :)

Comment: http://harmattan-dev.nokia.com/docs/library/html/qt4/qsettings.html#section-and-key-syntax

Comment: As @Tab has already pointed: "You can form hierarchical keys using the '/' character as a separator, similar to Unix file paths."

Answer (score 2):

Like @Tab and @vahancho pointed out, the [Qt Docs](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsettings.html#value) say the following about this:

> You can form hierarchical keys using the '/' character as a separator, similar to Unix file paths. For example:
>
> ```
> settings.setValue("mainwindow/size", win->size());
> settings.setValue("mainwindow/fullScreen", win->isFullScreen());
> settings.setValue("outputpanel/visible", panel->isVisible());
> ```

While not stated explicitly in the docs, deeper hierarchies (e.g., `mainwindow/titleBar/color`) are supported. When persisting a `QSettings` with the format set to [QSettings::IniFormat](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsettings.html#Format-enum) to a *.ini file on disk using `sync`, the top-level part of each hierarchical key (e.g., `mainwindow`) is mapped to an [Ini Section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2008-R2-and-2008/cc731332(v=ws.11)). Because the *ini* file format doesn't support nested sections, the rest of the key remains untouched and becomes the key inside the *ini* section. This can be seen in [`QConfFileSettingsPrivate::writeIniFile`](https://github.com/radekp/qt/blob/master/src/corelib/io/qsettings.cpp#L1882):

```
    if ((slashPos = key.indexOf(QLatin1Char('/'))) != -1) {
        section = key.left(slashPos);
        key.remove(0, slashPos + 1);
    }

    QSettingsIniSection &iniSection = iniMap[section];
    iniSection.keyMap[key] = j.value();
```

Thus, a setting like `settings.setValue("mainwindow/titleBar/color", "red");` becomes

```
[mainwindow]
titleBar/color = red
```

in the *ini* file.